# In illustrator, can i save files .pdf only (and preserving editing capabilities)?

Tags: pdf, file-handling, adobe-illustrator

While working with illustrator documents i often find myself saving the files twice.
One .ai file and a .pdf file.

Since .pdf files can be re-opened and edited in Illustrator i wondered if i should save in .pdf format only.

What's the point in keeping both files ?

Answer (score 0):

i always thought the same but stayed with AI/PSD mainly, because i feared incompability

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how much flexibility you want to maintain/retain as far as edit-ability. PDF and AI are two file formats aimed at achieving two different goals. As a rule of thumb, you always want to keep original design source files as you may lose certain design element details when converting over to PDF. Your starting point is your AI file. PDF is just one of many possibly outputs (like JPEG, PNG, BMP, PSD, SVG, print, etc) of your design in Illustrator. The point of keep the AI file is for any future reference and redesign.

It's ultimately up to you and how you intend to use and review those documents/designs.

Cheers